# Display the selectfield options after enter keyword at searchfield without click on the selectfield

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Enter Keyword : _________________ (searchfield)

Name :___________________ (selectfield)

Hello. Really need your helps.

I want to display the selectfield options without click on it. The selectfield options will display after user enter the keyword.

Example, I enter keyword of "am" , then at the name selectfield will display all the name that has "am" keyword. Usually, we need to click the selectfield to look and select one of the options.

But what i want to do is, after enter the keyword of "am" , the selectfields option right away pop up or showed all the name that has "am" keyword without click on the selectfield itself.

How to make it happen?  Thank you so much on your helps.

Comment: You mean to expand selectfield(combo) with values populated from keyword as I enter keyword ?

Comment: yes.. the selectfield automatically expand when I hit enter button